# Azure High Availability with a Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, high-availability, azure-availability-zones

I'm using a VM with an application that starts each 5 minutes executes some elaborations.
I'd like to achieve a VM with HA, but I cannot work with two VMs otherwise the two jobs would start at the same time, I can have only an application in execution in a time.

Azure provides any service for a similar scenario?

Can you help me? Thanks.
Bye.

Comment: When you say HA, what exactly do you mean? HA from data center or zone failure or HA from regional failures or hot standby or....

Comment: HA from regional zone, I'd like to get at least 99.95% of availability time

Comment: Any Single Instance Virtual Machine using Standard SSD Managed Disks for Operating System Disk and Data Disks, azure guarantee you will have Virtual Machine Connectivity of at least 99.5%. any Single Instance Virtual Machine using Premium SSD or Ultra Disk for all Operating System Disks and Data Disks,azure guarantee you will have Virtual Machine Connectivity of at least 99.9%. Anything above SLA, you would require 2 or more instances. More info here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_9/

Comment: So I don't need to have two VM, I can work with a VM with Standard SSD Managed disk without availability zones or other. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, thats correct - "For any Single Instance Virtual Machine using Standard SSD Managed Disks for Operating System Disk and Data Disks, we guarantee you will have Virtual Machine Connectivity of at least 99.5%."